# How to retrieve User-Added (Apps & Bookmarks) for an Authenticated User through an OKTA API Call?

Tags: api, sharepoint, bookmarks, okta

We have included list of all applications assigned to a User - as an applications ribbon - in a webpart in sharepoint. We have used this API call to retrieve the applications: 
https://alignedenergy.okta.com/api/v1/users/[user@domain]/appLinks

It works fine, but this retrieves ONLY the list of applications that are administrator governed.

Please advice: Why is it not returning the list of all org-defined and user-defined apps/bookmarks for every authenticated user from Okta?

We are in a hurry to complete the integration of OKTA and SHAREPOINT (waiting to release because of this problem).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why user-defined apps and bookmarks are not exposed through the API is because of privacy reasons. We strive to make sure our users 100% trust the Okta platform for handling their personal and sensitive information in the most secure and privacy-aware fashion.

What if a user creates a bookmark that points to a bank site he doesn't want the administrator to know about? We actually allow that and deny the ability even for an administrator or super use account (which is effectively the identity you impersonate with when using an Okta API key) to get access to that information.

Personal Okta apps and bookmarks are in Okta and should stay in Okta for privacy reasons. I hope that makes sense but feel free to send us a note at developers@okta.com if you want to discuss your needs further.